# Replace 'a' element from table cell to another using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have this table :

```
<table border="0" class="tab_cadrehov">
       <tbody>
           <tr class="tab_bg_1">
               <td valign="top"><a id="User_245_245" href="/dailyTickets/front/contacts.form.php?id=245">Gov0N</a></td>
               <td valign="top">ContactName</td>
               <td valign="top"><a href="mailto:ContactUser@gmail.com">ContactUser@gmail.com</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tab_bg_2">
                <td valign="top"><a id="User_695_695" href="/dailyTickets/front/contacts.form.php?id=695">iLgOP</a></td>
                <td valign="top">ihi</td>
                <td valign="top"><a href="mailto:yassYassine@gmail.com">yassYassine@gmail.com</a></td>
             </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

what i want is to delete the a element in each first td in the (`tr`,`table`) , and then give the deleted a element  to the second `td` element in the (`tr`,`table`) , to be like this :

```
  <tr class="tab_bg_1">
                   <td valign="top">Gov0N</td> // delete the a element from here , but keep the inside text  
                   <td valign="top"><a id="User_245_245" href="/dailyTickets/front/contacts.form.php?id=245">ContactName</a></td> // add it here , around the text
                .........
   </tr>
   <tr class="tab_bg_2">
                    <td valign="top">iLgOP</td>
                    <td valign="top"><a id="User_695_695" href="/dailyTickets/front/contacts.form.php?id=695">ihi</a></td>
                   .....

    </tr>
```

Comment: Hint: `.text()`, `.appendTo()`

Comment: @JanDvorak i have tried to get the `href` attr in each `td` element and then delete that `a` element , now i'm trying to wrap the `a` element in the second `td` with a element and `href` attr , i found some difficult so coz i'm new in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('td:first a');
    text_of_second_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    $(this).find('td:first').html(link.text()); //Link's text to the first td
    link.text(text_of_second_td); //Replace Link's text by the second td's text
    $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(link); //Link to the second td       
});
```

http://jsbin.com/afutir/1/

Comment: tnk you so much , it seems perfect , but why i'm getting the `[object Object]` ?

Comment: are u sure you tried the latest code..you can also see the working code in jsbin..